# Required member 'LogicalName' missing for field 'Target'

Tags: c#, odata, wcf-data-services, xrm

I'm using the [Microsoft XRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830281.aspx) to programmatically add an entity. However, each time I run a `.Create()` command I get the following error:

```
Required member 'LogicalName' missing for field 'Target'
```

First time using this service and similar resources in our company are scarce, so not sure what this error means or how to investigate/solve it.

Below is the class I created to handle the XRM communication. I instantiate each of the connection properties in the construtor. Then, in this case, call `CreateAgency(AgentTransmission agt)`. The exception is being thrown in the `CreateAgency()` method on the `.Create(account)` method call.

```
class DynamicsCommunication
{
    private Uri OrganizationUri = new Uri("http://devhildy03/xRMDRMu01/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
    private ClientCredentials credentials;
    private OrganizationServiceProxy servicePoxy;
    private Guid accountId;
    private Entity account;

    public DynamicsCommunication()
    {
        credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        servicePoxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, null, credentials, null);
        accountId = Guid.Empty;
    }

    public string UpdateDynamics(AgentTransmission agt)
    {
        switch (DeterminAction(agt))
        {
            case DynamicsAction.Create:
                return CreateAgency(agt);
            case DynamicsAction.Update:
                return UpdateAgency(agt);
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private string CreateAgency(AgentTransmission agt)
    {
        try
        {
            //Exception is thrown after this command
            accountId = servicePoxy.Create(CreateAccount(agt));

            if (accountId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return "error creating agency";
            }
        }
        catch (ODataException oEx)
        {
            string s = oEx.Message;
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string s = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }

    private Entity CreateAccount(AgentTransmission agt)
    {
        account = new Entity();
        account.Attributes.Add("LogicalName", "something");
        account.Attributes.Add("name", agt.AgencyName);
        account.Attributes.Add("telephone1", agt.BusinessPhone.Replace("(","").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", ""));
        account.Attributes.Add("address1_line1", agt.MailingStreet1);
        account.Attributes.Add("address1_city", agt.MailingCity);
        account.Attributes.Add("address1_postalcode", agt.MailingZip);
        account.Attributes.Add("neu_address1stateprovince", 1); //1 for Mailing
        account.Attributes.Add("neu_channelid", LookupChannelId(agt.Channel));
        account.Attributes.Add("neu_appointementstatus", "279660000");
        account.Attributes.Add("customertypecode", LookupCustomerCode(agt.RelationshipType));
        account.Attributes.Add("neu_taxid", UnobfuscateRef(agt.ReferenceNumber));

        return account;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the name of the CRM entity on the LogicalName property of the Entity object rather than adding it to the attribute collection

```
account = new Entity("your_entity_name");
```

or

```
account = new Entity();
account.LogicalName = "your_entity_name";
```